# Is there a way I can have anonymous users and authenticated users in a Mosquitto MQTT server?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

What I want to do is to `allow_anonymous true` and block unauthenticated users to certain topics.

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work as an anonymous client can still connect.

```
# anonymous users
topic deny /my/topic
# other topics should be fine...

user special
topic readwrite /my/topic
```

Comment: You need to edit the question to be clearer here. What do you mean by `connect`? If `allow_anonymous true` then anonymous users will always be able to connect to the broker, they can even subscribe to the topic, they just won't receive the messages.

Comment: Connect is what you just described there. To establish a connection with Mosquitto. Ok. Let me try what you just mentioned because I was expecting a `authentication has failed` type of message

Comment: Why did you expect them to not be allowed to connect when you have explicitly allowed it? Connecting to the broker is a totally separate step from subscribing to a topic

Comment: As I've subscribed to the topic which is suppossedly "denied" with
`mosquitto_sub -h my_host -t forbidden-topic`

Comment: Edit the question (not comments) to show exactly how you've configured the broker and how you've tested it.

Comment: @Some random IT boy - you're confusing "authentication" and "authorization". Authentication controls whether or not a client is allowed to connect to the broker; authorization determines what the client is allowed to do once it's connected. When those are clear you wouldn't expect a client that's not authorized to subscribe to a topic to ge an `authentication has failed` error because authentication and authorization are two entirely different things.

Comment: Great note @romkey thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example works as intended:

mosquitto.conf

```
allow_anonymous true
password_file passwd
acl_file acl

listener 1883 0.0.0.0
```

acl

```
topic deny foo
topic read #

user user
topic readwrite #
```

passwd

```
user:$7$101$efdj3nwLSpxELFhx$wB9Hls8c26//DFQdGMxb1gQt1muwNmdCMsbb1EZZjOV7Nc+fpTPVn9avsQQU2TF0gkJ3wXZjoltWrSAhSDLY2g==
```

anonymous user subscribed to both `foo` and `bar` topics

```
mosquitto_sub -v -t foo -t bar
bar test-bar
```

authenticated user publishing to both `foo` and `bar` topics

```
mosquitto_pub -u user -P secret -t foo -m test-foo
mosquitto_pub -u user -P secret -t bar -m test-bar
```

As you see the anonymous user only sees messages on the `bar` topic

Comment: I tested your comment hours ago and you were right, it just works. Glad you took the time to write a proper answer. This way I can upvote and accept your answer